# SubScript in SQL Server Data

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying for SQL server data having a subscript.

Below is what i am looking at :
Can we add ‘OS’ within brackets in a smaller font like ‘X (OS)’ or ‘(OS)’ where ever applicable in the brand level columns?

Comment: Please be more clear. I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Valid unicode subscript and superscript characters (like numbers, trademark symbols, etc) can be used as @gbn noted below, but if you want to place arbitrary text in subscript or superscript, you will need to use a markup language like HTML

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it you use nvarchar and the correct subscript/superscript characters.

```
DECLARE @test1 nvarchar(100),  @test2 varchar(100)
SET @test1 = N'Superx₀x₁x₂x₃x⁶x⁷x⁸xₒ' --OK
SET @test2 = 'Superx₀x₁x₂x₃x⁶x⁷x⁸xₒ' --broken
SELECT @test1, @test2
```

Edit: as per comment to question: formatting normal chars as subscript is a client problem